# In latex-mode is it possible to disable auto-fill-mode in between `\begin{figure}, \end{figure}`

Tags: latex

I am working on `tex` files with `LaTeX-mode`.
If possible, I want to use `auto-fill-mode`  in some conditions. I was wondering is it possible to disable it in  between some patterns like:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
…
\end{figure}
```

where I want to apply `auto-fill-mode` only for pure text? and not apply it under `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` or any matematical formula notations.

Comment: I've needed to solve this for a while, your question made me think of a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by defining your own `auto-fill-function`, and configuring LaTeX mode to use that:

```el
;; define environments we don't want to autofill:
(defvar unfillable-envs '("figure"))

;; add more environments if you like, eg:
;; (defvar unfillable-envs '("figure" "tikzpicture"))

;; create a function to check the environment first, then fill:
(defun my-filtered-fill ()
  (unless (member (LaTeX-current-environment) unfillable-envs)
    (do-auto-fill)))

;; setup LaTeX/AucTex to use auto-fill-mode, but with our fill-function:

(defun my-tex-auto-fill ()
  (auto-fill-mode)
  (setq auto-fill-function 'my-filtered-fill))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-tex-auto-fill)
```

Note that you can add different environments to `unfillable-envs` if you want to block filling in other places.

You could accomplish the same thing by advising the fill function, but that can lead to unexpected problems if you're not careful.

Comment: Can we add `tikzpicture` (in between `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}`) along with `figure`?

Comment: yes, just add it next to `"figure"`, like `'("figure" "tikzpicture")`

Comment: I have tried with example code under https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585898/127048 but it didn't work :-( When I add a character to a line it applies `auto-fill-mode`, does it work on your end?

Comment: Yes, it works for me

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add an entry like `("figure" current-indentation)` to `LaTeX-indent-environment-list`?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ArashEsbati maybe. If you have a better answer, feel free to add it. I haven't looked at this in over a year, and don't use AucTeX regularly for a long time now.